# How to handle large number of RegEx patterns when using Regex.CompileToAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to compile a list of regular expression to an assembly.

I found that the 'Name' value that must be different for each RegexCompilationInfo objects, so when compiled they are different objects.

However say I have many RegEx patterns (like say close to 100).  Setting s name on each one of those and maintaining those names seems like it will be difficult.  Not only that each time I want to check a text for each pattern (which I do)  I have to know all the names and instantiate each of the objects by its name to use it)

Is there an easier way to handle this?

```
        List<RegexCompilationInfo> compilationList = new List<RegexCompilationInfo>();

        compilationList.Add(new RegexCompilationInfo(@"pattern1",RegexOptions.CultureInvariant,"Name1","Namespace.Space",true));
        compilationList.Add(new RegexCompilationInfo(@"pattern2", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant, "Name2", "Namespace.Space", true));
        ...
        ...
        compilationList.Add(new RegexCompilationInfo(@"pattern100", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant, "Name100", "Namespace.Space", true));

        // Apply AssemblyTitle attribute to the new assembly
        //
        // Define the parameter(s) of the AssemblyTitle attribute's constructor 
        Type[] parameters = { typeof(string) };
        // Define the assembly's title
        object[] paramValues = { "Library of compiled regular expressions" };
        // Get the ConstructorInfo object representing the attribute's constructor
        ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute).GetConstructor(parameters);
        // Create the CustomAttributeBuilder object array
        CustomAttributeBuilder[] attBuilder = { new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctor, paramValues) };

        // Generate assembly with compiled regular expressions
        RegexCompilationInfo[] compilationArray = new RegexCompilationInfo[compilationList.Count];
        AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName("RegexLib, Version=1.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        compilationList.CopyTo(compilationArray);
        Regex.CompileToAssembly(compilationArray, assemName, attBuilder);
```

Usage

```
  Name1 name1Regex = new Name1(); 
  Name2 name2Regex = new Name2();
  ..
  ...

  if (name1Regex.Matches(text).Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For naming the patterns, you could just use an incrementing index. `"name" + index`.

You could use reflection to load all patterns into a list

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("RegexLib, Version=1.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
var patterns = new List<Regex>();
foreach (var type in asm.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (typeof(Regex).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        patterns.Add((Regex) Activator.CreateInstance(type));
    }
}
return patterns;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still must specify the names for each Regex pattern?  Is there any way around that problem?

Comment: Alternatively, I was thinking instead of compiling, since all i want to do is check a text against all the patterns, using the static Regex methods while looping over the patterns that I can store in a string array.

Comment: Yes you do need to name each regex, but Markus shows a way here that does not require you to know those names when you use the compiled regexes... You just loop over the list of instantiated Regex objects.
And as the names would be irrelevant for you, applying **'name' + index** seems very sound to me.